# What's the noticeable speed difference between these two Mac computers?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, performance, productivity

Someone wants to trade his new iPhone 5, his 20" iMac, and some cash for my 15" Macbook Pro. Here are the specs for my MBP and his iMac:

**My Early 2011 15in Macbook Pro**

```
2.2GHz i7
4GB Ram
AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB
750GB HDD
1GB GDDR5 Graphics memory
```

**Their mid 2007 20" iMac**

```
2.4GHz Intel Core 2 duo
ATI Radeon HD 2600 Pro 256 MB
4GB RAM 667 MHz DDR2
```

And it's other specs..

**Will either machine be significantly/noticeably faster?** Again, the comparison is on the basis of speed alone.

Comment: Can you clear up your question, get rid of some extraneous details and personal storyline?

Comment: At first sight: yes there is a huge difference you will definitely notice. However, this also heavily relies on the programs you are using. If you check the benchmarks for the cpu's you will notice they are way out of eachothers league...

Comment: Speed to do what? How is this going to be of use to the site in general? This might be improved if you asked "… and what next?" several times and elaborated what problem you are trying to solve. This might be fine in chat, but it [seems too much gorilla vs. shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look on everymac.com i see the following Geekbench measurements

MBP pro     32bit=9991/64bit=10823

Imac 2007   32bit=3216/64bit=3595

with this info i would say yes. by a whole lot..

I'm writing this info funnily enough on a 2007 imac 20 inch so i think its a good machine...and it still going strong but it has its limitations that become apparent as soon as you leave OSX 10.6 and go to 10.7 or 10.8...

So if you use your mac for lets say web browsing and light apps then it does its job... its memory limit is 6GB by the way...

But if you want to use it for music/video editing creating etc.. With current versions of suitable applications then i would say that would be a GREAT downgrade...

Also if its any help according to everymac.com:

MBP pro  estimated current price US$1200-US$1350

Imac2007 estimated current price US$750-US$850